# Phalaenopsis Orchid identification - purple veins

Tags: identification, orchids

Like the title says - can you help me identify this orchid? It's a phalaenopsis, but what hybrid exactly? (I'm looking for a recognised hybrid name, not a flower shop generic one)

[image: NOID orchid]

A "little" bit of research led me to several guesses, amongst which [Brother Stripes or Chih Shang's stripes](http://hybridorchid.la.coocan.jp/Phalaenopsis/) (is the only difference between the two the 'broadness' of Chich Shang?), [New stripes](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/836051118296945867/), [Taisuco stripe](https://learninglab.si.edu/resources/view/1763302), and the [Sogo Tyler](https://learninglab.si.edu/resources/view/2124303). There are so many similar varieties, and I can't believe that they can be so similar yet considered different hybrids. But I'm new to orchids, so maybe this is normal? Or these are different names for the same thing (like 'Bee Sting' is florists' name for 'Chiada Francis Picotee'?)

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely difficult to answer. There are so many Phalaenopsis hybrids.The one's you've listed don't look right. try r/orchids
I found this link, but who knows if it is a real name or just a made up one: https://www.vazonchik.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/bro-red-king-8cm.jpg

Comment: Thanks! What is r/orchid? I know there are special forums for orchids, but since I already have a StackExchange account, I decided to give it a try here first.

Comment: http://reddit.com/r/orchid

Comment: Thanks again. The 'brother red king' looks a little too intense/concentrated in colour. Can you elaborate on what's wrong with the ones I've listed?